# SQL Checking if a pair of tuple has at least one match in a different table

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 tables: `member` and `purchase`

Members can belong to multiple clubs and purchases are done through clubs. So for example member A can belong to 3 clubs, and can buy one item through club A and one item through club B.

Both member and purchase contain a member ID and club name.

How can I determine if a member has purchased an item (doesn't matter how many) from every club they are a part of?

Edit: This is part of a greater homework problem to find members who have not purchased a book from every club they are in. My idea is to use an EXCEPT clause to remove everyone who has purchased a book from every club they are in but I am having difficulty on this part.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of distinct clubs a member has a purchase with, and compare it to the total number of clubs:

```
SELECT     m.*
FROM       members m
JOIN       (SELECT   member_id, COUNT(DISTINCT club_id) AS club_purchases
            FROM     purchases
            GROUP BY member_id) p ON m.member_id = p.member_id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT club_id) AS all_clubs
            FROM   purchases) c
WHERE      club_purchases = all_clubs
```